Deploying BLE heart rate reader on Xcode using the given SDK
I'm pretty new to swift and Xcode, I'm building an app on it, but I'm having some issues deploying real time heart data, and I can't seem to be able to fix the problem on my own. Thank you in advance, and questions please do let me know in the comments.
Any help will be appreciated, I'm finding no related projects where they successfully deploy or use their Sdk, The Device I'm trying to read the heart rate data from is a watch its name: Polar Ignite 3, which falls under the conditions required to get real time heart rate data from the ble sdk link provided below.
The PolarBleSDK on GitHub page: https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk
I'm having problems with my code, as the new update on the SDK, some of the code does not allow me to build the app in the first place, i will provide the code below and mark what errors I'm getting from the Xcode, can you help me fix those errors thank you, the code is below can you please help me address these issues as otherwise I cant bypass the build stage on Xcode unless it is resolved:
ContentView.swift file: No seen issues on the ContentView.swift file.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

u/StateObject var bleManager = BLEManager()

var body: some View {

VStack {

Text("BLE Communication")

.font(.largeTitle)

.padding()

Button(action: {

bleManager.startScanning()

}) {

Text("Connect to Polar Device")

.padding()

.background(Color.blue)

.foregroundColor(.white)

.cornerRadius(10)

}

.padding()

Text(bleManager.isBluetoothOn ? "Bluetooth is on. Ready to connect." : "Bluetooth is off.")

.foregroundColor(bleManager.isBluetoothOn ? .green : .red)

.padding()

Text("Device State: \(bleManager.deviceConnectionState.description)")

.padding()

.foregroundColor(.orange)

Text("Heart Rate: \(bleManager.heartRate) bpm")

.padding()

.foregroundColor(.purple)

}

.onAppear {

bleManager.startScanning()

}

}

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

static var previews: some View {

ContentView()

}

}

BLEManager.swift file: 3 issues on the BLEManager.swift file such as,

Type 'BLEManager' does not conform to protocol 'PolarBleApiDeviceHrObserver', add stubs for conformance. Marked at Line 23 with "&&1&&".

Type 'PolarBleSdkFeature' has no member 'hr'. Marked at Line 33 with "&&2&&".

Type 'deviceHrObserver' is deprecated: The functionality has changed. Please use the startHrStreaming API to get the heart rate data. Marked at Line 35 with "&&3&&".


import Foundation

import CoreBluetooth

import PolarBleSdk

import RxSwift

enum DeviceConnectionState {

case disconnected(String)

case connecting(String)

case connected(String)

var description: String {

switch self {

case .disconnected(let deviceId):

return "Disconnected from \(deviceId)"

case .connecting(let deviceId):

return "Connecting to \(deviceId)"

case .connected(let deviceId):

return "Connected to \(deviceId)"

}

}

}

class BLEManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, PolarBleApiObserver, PolarBleApiDeviceHrObserver, PolarBleApiPowerStateObserver {         "&&1&&"

u/Published var isBluetoothOn: Bool = false

u/Published var deviceConnectionState: DeviceConnectionState = .disconnected("")

u/Published var heartRate: Int = 0

private var polarApi: PolarBleApi!

private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

override init() {

super.init()

polarApi = PolarBleApiDefaultImpl.polarImplementation(DispatchQueue.main, features: Set<PolarBleSdkFeature>([.hr]))             "&&2&&"

polarApi.observer = self

polarApi.deviceHrObserver = self         "&&3&&"

polarApi.powerStateObserver = self

isBluetoothOn = polarApi.isBlePowered

}

func startScanning() {

polarApi.searchForDevice()

.observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)

.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] deviceInfo in

print("Discovered device: \(deviceInfo.name)")

if deviceInfo.name.contains("Polar Ignite 3") {

do {

try self?.polarApi.connectToDevice(deviceInfo.deviceId)

} catch {

print("Failed to connect to device: \(error)")

}

}

}, onError: { error in

print("Device search failed: \(error)")

})

.disposed(by: disposeBag)

}

func startHeartRateStreaming(deviceId: String) {

polarApi.startHrStreaming(deviceId)

.observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)

.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] hrData in

if let firstSample = hrData.first {

self?.heartRate = Int(firstSample.hr)

print("Heart Rate: \(firstSample.hr)")

}

}, onError: { error in

print("HR streaming failed: \(error)")

})

.disposed(by: disposeBag)

}

// PolarBleApiPowerStateObserver

func blePowerOn() {

isBluetoothOn = true

print("Bluetooth is on")

}

func blePowerOff() {

isBluetoothOn = false

print("Bluetooth is off")

}

// PolarBleApiObserver

func deviceConnecting(_ polarDeviceInfo: PolarDeviceInfo) {

deviceConnectionState = .connecting(polarDeviceInfo.deviceId)

print("Connecting to device: \(polarDeviceInfo.name)")

}

func deviceConnected(_ polarDeviceInfo: PolarDeviceInfo) {

deviceConnectionState = .connected(polarDeviceInfo.deviceId)

print("Connected to device: \(polarDeviceInfo.name)")

startHeartRateStreaming(deviceId: polarDeviceInfo.deviceId)

}

func deviceDisconnected(_ polarDeviceInfo: PolarDeviceInfo, pairingError: Bool) {

deviceConnectionState = .disconnected(polarDeviceInfo.deviceId)

print("Disconnected from device: \(polarDeviceInfo.name)")

}

// PolarBleApiDeviceHrObserver

func hrValueReceived(_ identifier: String, data: PolarHrData) {

if let firstSample = data.first {

heartRate = Int(firstSample.hr)

print("Heart rate received: \(firstSample.hr) bpm")

}

}

}

my info.plist file: No seen issues on the info.plist file.
<?xml version=**"1.0" **encoding=**"UTF-8"**?>

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC** "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"**>

<plist version="1.0">

<dict>

<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>

<string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>

<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>

<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>

<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>

<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>

<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>

<string>6.0</string>

<key>CFBundleName</key>

<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>

<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>

<string>FMWK</string>

<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>

<string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>

<key>CFBundleVersion</key>

<string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>

<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>

<string></string>

<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>

<true/>

<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>

<string>LaunchScreen</string>

<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>

<array>

<string>armv7</string>

</array>

<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>

<array>

<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>

<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>

<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>

</array>

<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>

<array>

<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>

<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>

<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>

<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>

</array>

<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>

<string>This app needs Bluetooth access to communicate with ARCx Ring and Polar Ignite 3.</string>

<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>

<string>This app needs Bluetooth access to communicate with peripheral devices.</string>

</dict>

</plist>

Package Dependencies:PolarBleSdk 5.5.0
RxSwift 6.5.0
SwiftProtobuf 1.26.0

Look at the protocol PolarBleApiDeviceHrObserver, you don't respects it. That's why, you are using func hrValueReceived(_ identifier: String, data: PolarHrData) but it's not the PolarBleApiDeviceHrObserver method... Plus the new one is deprecated. Which version were you using before the update?

Regarding the .hr it seems it's been (badly renamed in not very Swift). See https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/blob/1f7a846a200c7fd3737ae6a6ecf5dce68b1e54a5/sources/iOS/ios-communications/Sources/PolarBleSdk/sdk/api/PolarBleApi.swift#L19 to find the real value. Or just type PolarBleSdkFeature. and let XCode autocompletion help you

Regarding the deprecated, read https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/blob/1f7a846a200c7fd3737ae6a6ecf5dce68b1e54a5/documentation/MigrationGuide5.0.0.md and implement the new one if you want (though the a deprecated method should still work but gives a warning, not a compile error)
